# How to refresh scripts everytime any component is mounted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I am using some jQuery scripts that has animation effects..

Due to that it has animation effects which have to work again and again whenever something is rendered on the page, jQuery scripts should also be refreshed. But the problem is that jQuery scripts are not refreshed.

Here is my router:

```
export default () => (
  <div>
    <Menu />
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact path="/"
        render={({ staticContext, match }) => {
          const site = staticContext
            ? staticContext.site
            : location.hostname.split(".")[0]
          return <UniversalComponent site={site} match={match} page="core/Home" />
        }}
      />
...
```

As you see I have a `<Menu />` component outside of Switch. And that is where loads jQuery scripts.

```
class Menu extends Component {
    _isMounted = false;
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isDataFetched: false
        };
        this.loadExternalScripts = this.loadExternalScripts.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.loadExternalScripts().then(() => {
            if (this._isMounted) {
                this.setState({ isDataFetched: true });
            }
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    async loadExternalScripts() {
        const postscribe = require('postscribe');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.9.0/js/all.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/waypoints.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/lightbox.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/owl.carousel.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/jquery.counterup.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/validator.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/contact.js"></script>');
        await postscribe('#react-root', '<script src="/vendor/js/custom.js"></script>');
    }
...
```

Using "**postscribe**" library, I load all the required jQuery scripts.

Among them, scripts related Navigation toggle button, it works well, because navigation toggle things has nothing to do with being refreshed or not.

However, scripts related to animation, which should be refreshed whenever any pages is loaded, they only work for 1st time, then doesn't work anymore. Because jQuery can be loaded only the first time when the menu component was loaded.

It looked like that `componentDidMount()` in Menu class is not triggered (which will refresh jQuery if triggered, I guess) when react router make changes for moving the pages. This is what I think the problem, but not sure.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: It seems that your scripts are cached. Just add unique (timestamp) query to each URL to prevent caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***componentDidUpdate***  will come in handy here
Basically what ***componentDidUpdate*** does is takes two arguments (prevProps, prevState) and runs anytime a prop is changed or the state is updated.

So as a simple example you could do something like this in your component

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
// Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (prevProps.propThatReceiveChanges !== this.props.propThatReceiveChanges){
  this.loadExternalScripts().then(() => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({ isDataFetched: true });
        }
    });
```

}
    }

> **Note**
>
> ***componentDidUpdate()*** will not be invoked if ***shouldComponentUpdate()*** returns false.